# Recaptcha with devise is not working on ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, recaptcha

I get this error:

> There has been an unexpected error with the application. Please contact the administrator. error code: success

I am using recaptcha with devise, I edited where appropriate as stated by following the steps mentioned on [this page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Use-Recaptcha-with-Devise)

Here is my `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

gem 'json'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'will_paginate', "3.0.pre4"

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails'
  gem "letter_opener"
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "carrierwave"
gem "fastercsv"
gem 'devise', '2.1.2'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'mailman', :require=> false
gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'prawn'
gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails'
```

Comment: What have you got in Gemfile ?

Comment: gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'json'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'will_paginate', "3.0.pre4"
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails'
  gem "letter_opener"
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "carrierwave"
gem "fastercsv"
gem 'devise', '2.1.2'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'mailman', :require=> false
gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'prawn'
#gem "ruby-recaptcha"
gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails'

Comment: hi, here is my gem file, do u see anything weird in it? thanks for your help

Comment: I cannot see anything missing on the Gem file. Which version of Ruby and Rails are you using?

Comment: my versions are as follows: ruby 1.8.7  and Rails 3.2.8   thanks so much for your continual support and help

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have followed it exactly what it says on [the documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Use-Recaptcha-with-Devise) For instance, to support recaptcha on ruby 1.8.X and 1.9.X, there are different line of code. However, after a short research I found out this [website](http://thekindofme.wordpress.com/2010/09/25/recaptcha-with-rails-3-without-plugins/) you can use recaptcha without the plugins regardless of your rails version. I hope this helps. :)

Comment: i followed the directions according to the documentation and i used the website you gave me, i also followed other examples from various websites (ok, i did alot of research on it but i dint get anywhere). ok, i will redo it once more and post my findings. thanks for your help

Comment: I hope you are creating a separate Test Rails App to test the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

From Recaptcha Site (almost).... I'm in Rails 4 with Devise (aparently the hard bundle).. No, is too easy. Procedure apply to any ruby, any rails, and devise (or without devise). Tested in ruby/rails/devise 1.9.3/3.2.x/2.2.1 & 2.0.x/4.0.x/3.2.4 and last one without Devise.

Edit next files:

Gemfile

```
gem 'ruby-recaptcha'
# bundle install
```

config/initializers/credentials.rb (any file in this path it's ok)

```
# Set constants
RCC_PUB = "your_public_key"
RCC_PRIV= "your_private_key"
# re-start server. Try to keep safety this data using ENV vars.
```

app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb (or form you prefer)

```
# form
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :email, autofocus: true, required: true %>
    ...
    <!-- Add next line -->
    <div id="captchadiv"></div>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Register", class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
<% end %
```

At the end of same file (can be in awesome_funcs.js.erb file)

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function () {
    function showRecaptcha() {
        Recaptcha.create("<%= RCC_PUB %>", "captchadiv", {
            theme: "white",
            lang: 'en'
        });
    };
    showRecaptcha();
});
</script>
```

And the little trick, app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
# On top
include ReCaptcha::AppHelper
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
# If already you have this method or any other with before_filter

# Into method
protected
def configure_permitted_parameters
    if controller_name == "registrations" && action_name == "create"
    # Rails 3: If you prefer, put this into registrations#create method
        unless validate_recap(params, User.new.errors) # Or your model
            # wrong input is handled here
            flash[:error] = "Text from images doesn't match with your input"
            redirect_to :back # or other stuff
            # As my submit is with Ajax, I do a render instead redirect:
            # render :json => {other: "recaptcha_failed"}
            # In success callback I evaluate response and Recaptcha.reload() paints a new recaptcha.
        end
    end
    .... 
    # trick: do everything before params sanitizers
end
```

As we are using Ajax plugin, finally, add in
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
(just before end of body)

```
<body>
    ...
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script>
</body>
```

That's it. You have recaptcha

Advice:
If you use Ajax to do submit, you can use success callback for a Recaptcha.reload() in case images and input doesn't match.

Other, if your form is "remote: true", you can use above behavior after "create" method in create.js.erb file in your views directory.

IMPORTANT: In some projects when form arrives from a link Recaptcha doesn't appear. Try to locate the launcher link into a div or in a parent div add "data-no-turbolink". I had this issue in Rails 4.